# Is it possible to build a Science-based medieval fantasy world?

Tags: science-based, magic, medieval, mythical-creatures, scientific-development

For instance, I'm currently building a fantasy world set in medieval times in a fictional world. I'm very keen on Science and I would like to combine the two. I thought that the characters could collect items (like amulets) which consisted of different elements, and that each of these elements had a specific reaction. For instance, an item that contained Helium and that it could heal creatures. Is it a good idea? Could it work? Or is it too much?

Comment: Science is incompatible with "amulets" which contain "healing helium". You are making a most regrettable confusion between science and magic. They are both perfectly respectable fields of investigation, but they are profoundly different. Ah, and "a medieval world based on science" is like "a communist world based on private property" -- it's self contradictory. The essence of the medieval world is that it's based on hierarchical relationships of fealty between persons or families; secondarily, it's based on a multitude of small almost completely autarkic and isolated domains.

Comment: There was a significant amount of science in medieval times, especially in Islamic countries. I suggest that you start looking there, or to the Greeks if you are interested in earlier periods. I suggest that you forget about 'elements in boxes', though.

Comment: Just because they sound similar doesn't mean Helium has anything to do with healing.

Comment: Im going to avoid going on a rant and simply state this is horribly contradictory.

Comment: @leeleon - your definition for "Science" must be very lax. Yes, there were people lucky enough to be able to engage in something akin to research. They investigated certain principles that caught their fancy. But the vast majority of them were not impartial, or objective. Also, you're attributing an interesting amount of credit to "Islamic countries", which is a bit of a historical myth. The real centers for learning and innovation were the Romans/Greeks, then for a little while Turkey, and finally the Italian states, and Western Europe, with China having its own parallel until the 1800's.

Comment: However, there are some excellent examples of "scientifically-based fantasy", including Terry Brook's Shannara series which (spoilers) starts out reading like high (very medieval) fantasy but quickly evolves into a post-apocalyptic.  For example, the magic user's "wand of light" stops working when its batteries wear out.

Comment: @AndreiROM - my definition for "science" is generous, taking into account that it was still evolving proper methodologies, but the point is that it was there. "Science" as we know it today, did not arrive suddenly and to consider the middle ages as being without it is naive. Admittedly, it got mixed up a lot with magic and religion, but that was the medieval world - there were still grains of science there.

Comment: Science that looks like magic.  Check, I'm there.  "For instance, an item that contained Helium and that it could heal creatures."  You've lost me.  What's scientific about that?  That's crackpot alchemy at best.  You seem to actually be looking for ways to drape your magic in scientific terminology.  Could it work?  As magic?  Or as science?  What are the constraints under which we should answer?